# Make Ctrl-Page Up, Ctrl-Page Down work in VirtualBox guest

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard

I'm on Windows VirtualBox use windows guests, seems like Ctrl-Page Up/Page Down don't work in them. Personally I need this for [Far manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAR_Manager), it's a console app, but I checked this in gui apps (including firefox) and this don't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the right Control Key is the `Host Key` - which assists with the capture and release of the mouse cursor and other features like switching between full screen mode and windowed. You aren't by chance using that key only to find it isn't working as expected?

I used [Keyposé](http://katastrophos.net/magnus/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/keypose.zip) to show the captured keystrokes and it is definitely capturing the Control+PageUp chord in a Windows 8 VM.

Can you provide some additional details, such as the version of VirtualBox installed, the guest operating system version and if you have the guest additions installed?

Comment: The host is VirtualBox-4.2.6-82870-Win.exe, the guest is Windows XP SP3, Guest additions installed from the corresponding menu item. Your answer led me to a version that there two kind of catching such key sequences, it's when Control press  is determined with GetKeyState function or if they're detected as two general keys. Probably the first is not working since the Control has special meaning.

Comment: Finally I changed the Host key to a different one and right Control-Page Up/Down started working as I expected. Thanks